# Smart and permanent aggregation of multiple RSS feeds

Tags: webapp-rec, rss

Many of the sites I use provide RSS activity feeds. Right now, I merge them together using FriendFeed, in order to aggregate all my online activity in a single place, and maintain a permanent record. However, Friendfeed seems to be lagging behind since the acquisition by Facebook, and I'm considering switching.

I don't really care about the whole social aspect, I just want to merge multiple feeds, and access them from a single place. Service-specific logic is not strictly necessary, support for plain RSS would be enough. But there are some other requirements that are not satisfied by most simple RSS aggregators I've tried (eg. Yahoo Pipes).

- It should be very simple to add new sources, and retroactive import would be great.
- Copies of entries should be stored, as most feeds don't preserve the past (this is crucial).
- Everything should be exportable in a reasonable format.
- Output readable both for humans (HTML) and machines (RSS) would be nice.
- Once configured, it should work without any manual intervention.

Do you know a service like that, or do I have to code it myself?

Comment: Have you looked at Google reader?

Comment: I should have added this to the bounty message, but I'm thinking Windows and not Mac -- ideally, should be a web app that's platform agnostic.

Comment: Due to the aftermath of terrible weather, I haven't had a chance to evaluate all of these equally, but I had been looking into Pinboard as an option, and I really like IFTTT.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to forego the convenience of a one stop solution, you could create such an archival system out of two components:

- get a [Pinboard](http://pinboard.in) archival account to your name. It’s called an “archival” account because it does, in fact, store the full page linked to by your bookmark, including media, and indexes it for full-text retrieval. It also archives your tweets directly.
- get an [ifttt](http://ifttt.com/) account and set up connectors storing you activities as bookmarks in your Pinboard account. ifttt is a service making it very simple to create connectors between web services of the kind “*if* new status post on Facebook *then* create a link on Pinboard with description = status”.

You will end with a system steadily adding to a list of links (with descriptions and tags set according to your ifttt configuration) whose targets are archived by Pinboard. Pinboard offers both an [RSS feed of additions](https://pinboard.in/howto/#rss) and [export of bookmarks](https://pinboard.in/howto/#export) as well as of [archived data](https://pinboard.in/faq/#download_archived).

Note the Pinboard archival count incurs a fee – but you haven’t specified “free” in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I use [NewsFire](http://www.newsfirerss.com/) for that. It has all your requirements.

Comment: Both of your suggestions look great, but are Mac specific, which won't work for me...

Comment: You should add this on your requirements ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should also have a look at [Vienna](http://www.vienna-rss.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I use [FeedsAnywhere](http://feedsanywhere.com/feed/all). It's very minimalist, but you can customize many account and display settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised none of the answers mention [Google Reader](http://reader.google.com). Really easy to use and very handy if you only have basic needs. It also has decent import/export functionality, but the ability to easily access all my RSS feeds from anywhere - including my mobile - is great. There's even an Android app (probably iOS too), but I find the site is more than good enough on its own.

Comment: The rub with Google Reader is that, although it does permanently aggregate all items, you cannot export that aggregate data. Besides a list of your subscribed feeds (exportable via OPML, which is pretty much standard interop for feed readers), all you can export is *content you have somehow interacted with* (starred, commented, liked – note all of these are gone now anyway as sharing functionality has been folded into Google+. The JSON format used isn’t easily transferrable either).

Comment: Google Reader is being permanently closed on July 1, 2013, in any case.

Comment: Yeah I totally should have seen that coming a year and a half in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [tumblr](http://tumblr.com/). They have built-in support for Facebook and Twitter, and allow up to 5 other general RSS feeds. [Read about importing feeds](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/feeds).

Comment: Thanks, but I've already checked Tumblr. There are a few problems: 1) five feeds is definitely not enough, 2) they say "you must log into Tumblr frequently", so it's not fully automatic, 3) the delays can be huge.