# Automatically download plain text from multiple RSS feeds

Tags: rss

Can anyone think of a robust, local, archival system for the plain text contents of RSS feeds?

It appears as though a similar question was asked here ([Smart and permanent aggregation of multiple RSS feeds](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14608/smart-and-permanent-aggregation-of-multiple-rss-feeds)) but I don't know that the proposed solution, a combination of Pinboard and IFTTT, would scale nicely to thousands of feeds.

My requirements would be exactly the same as in the previous question:

- It should be simple to add new sources, and retroactive import would be great.
- Copies of entries should be stored, as most feeds don't preserve the past (this is crucial).
- Everything should be exportable in a reasonable (preferably plain text) format, and metadata would be nice
- Output readable both for humans (HTML) and machines (RSS) would be nice
  nice
- Once configured, it should work without any manual intervention (also crucial)

I am currently using Google Reader to manage around 500 RSS feeds, but Reader doesn't support downloading the contents of the feeds. I've tried other aggregators, including standalone Linux clients such as Liferea, but none seem to have the functionality I'm looking for.

(Ultimately, this setup would be used for long-term trend analysis from media sources.)

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean Google Reader doesn't support downloading the content ?
https://www.google.com/reader/view/feed/http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot ->
https://www.google.com/reader/atom/feed/http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot?n=3

Granted , you will have to do some manual work for any feeds with over a 1000 items.
[How to raise Google Reader RSS feed entry limit?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26567/how-to-raise-google-reader-rss-feed-entry-limit)
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/reader/continuation/reader/vFOVmRUVMOE/0k3P-kxVZfQJ

Answer (score -2):

you need a web app called IFTTT (IF THIS THEN THEN THAT) For example if a RSS feed or a Google Reader Fed, have news then Send it To Email, Dropbox, or Google drive, etc (as a text file attachment)

Check all channeles available on https://ifttt.com/channels